# How Insert an expression in legend in ggplot2?:: correct color + multiple lines and point

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am new to R and have not been able to correct the following graph.
Xb_exp, it should have blue dots.
Xb_dw, solid red line.
Xb_f, dotted line.
Xb_s,  longdash line.
The legend expression should be as shown with the subscript.
I have not been able to correct it.
Is there a way to do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IxpX.png)

```
my data
CA <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30)
Xb_exp <- c(0.0231,0.0519,0.0839,0.1197,0.1595,0.1996,0.2384,0.2772,0.3153,0.3520,0.3887,0.4254,0.4615,0.4978,0.5339,0.5685,0.6000,0.6279,0.6528,0.6762,0.6974,0.7166,0.7346,0.7516,0.7669,0.7810,0.7940,0.8059)
Xb_dw <- c(0.0160,0.0516,0.0886,0.1259,0.1633,0.2006,0.2377,0.2749,0.3122,0.3496,0.3870,0.4245,0.4617,0.4984,0.5339,0.5678,0.5996,0.6288,0.6551,0.6786,0.6994,0.7179,0.7346,0.7499,0.7641,0.7774,0.7899,0.8018)
Xb_f <- c(0.0021,0.0031,0.0046,0.0067,0.0095,0.0131,0.0177,0.0234,0,0387,0.0483,0.0591,0.0709,0.0832,0.0955,0.1073,0.1181,0.1272,0.1345,0.1398,0.1443,0.1456,0.1468,0.1474,0.1476,0.1477,0.1477,0.1477,0.1477)
Xb_s <- c(0.0139,0.0484,0.0839,0.1192,0.1538,0.1874,0.2200,0.2515,0.2818,0.3108,0.3387,0.3653,0.3908,0.4151,0.4383,0.4604,0.4815,0.5015,0.5206,0.5387,0.5559,0.5722,0.5877,0.6024,0.6164,0.6264,0.6421,0.6040)

dat <- c(CA, Xb_exp, Xb_dw, Xb_f, Xb_s)

my code

labels =  c(expression(X[b_exp]),expression(X[b_dw]),expression(X[b_f]),expression(X[b_s]))
color4 <- c("Xb_exp"="#3C5488FF", "Xb_dw"="#DC0000FF", "Xb_f"="#00A087FF", "Xb_s"="#4DBBD5FF")
Xb_D1 <- ggplot(data = dat) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x="Crank position (ºCA)", y= bquote('Burn fraction ('~X[b]~')')) +
  geom_point(aes(x=CA, y=Xb_exp, colour="Xb_exp"), size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(x=CA, y=Xb_dw,colour="Xb_dw"), size=1,linetype="solid") +
  geom_line(aes(x=CA, y=Xb_f,colour="Xb_f"), size=1,linetype="dotted") +
  geom_line(aes(x=CA, y=Xb_s,colour="Xb_s"), size=1,linetype="longdash") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=color4, labels=labels) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),legend.position = c(0.8, 0.5), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2,80))
plot(Xb_D1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically, setting this up with conventional ploting is rather simple:

Given all the data above:

```r
linetypes4 <- c( Xb_exp=NA, Xb_dw="solid", Xb_f="dotted", Xb_s="longdash" )

plot(
    NA, type="n", xlim=c(0,30), ylim=c(0,0.8),
    xlab = "Crank position (ºCA)", ylab = bquote('Burn fraction ('~X[b]~')'),
    panel.first = grid()
)
with( dat, {
    points( x=CA, y=Xb_exp, pch=19, col=color4["Xb_exp"], size=3 )
    for( n in c("Xb_dw", "Xb_f", "Xb_s")) {
        lines( x=CA, y=get(n), lty=linetypes[n], col=color4[n], lwd=2 )
    }
})
legend(
    x = "right",
    legend = labels,
    col = color4,
    lty = linetypes4,
    pch = c(19,NA,NA,NA),
    box.lwd = 0,
    inset = .02
)
```

[image: with proper labels]

Comment: Thanks Sirius. There is a way to use the subscript in the label expression (Xb_exp, Xb_dw, Xb_f, Xb_s). X(normal) and b_exp(subscript)

Answer (score 1):

ggplot() requires a dataframe not a vector.  If you modify your code with:

`dat <- data.frame(CA, Xb_exp, Xb_dw, Xb_f, Xb_s)`

and fix the typo in your Xb_f vector

`Xb_f <- c(0.0021,0.0031,0.0046,0.0067,0.0095,0.0131,0.0177,0.0234,0.0387,0.0483,0.0591,0.0709,0.0832,0.0955,0.1073,0.1181,0.1272,0.1345,0.1398,0.1443,0.1456,0.1468,0.1474,0.1476,0.1477,0.1477,0.1477,0.1477)`

Your remaining code will work as but could be achieved more simply using the tidyverse approach below.  Use pivot_longer to stack the y variables against your x variable.

````
dat %>% 
pivot_longer(Xb_exp:Xb_s) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = CA, y = value, colour = name)) +
 geom_point() + 
 geom_line() +
 scale_colour_manual(values=color4, labels=labels) +
 theme_bw() +
 theme(legend.title = element_blank(),legend.position = c(0.8, 0.5),
 legend.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
 scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2,80)) + 
 labs(x="Crank position (ºCA)", y= bquote('Burn fraction ('~X[b]~')')) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code suggesting you didn't try what you pasted.

1. `0,0387,` in your data should likely be `0.0387,` otherwise nothing is right (no data measures several hundreds in there)
2. `c(CA, ... )` should likely be `data.frame( CA, ... )`

Now, the first problem is you are doing all the heavy lifting yourself, while ggplot sits there with nothing left to do. It was designed to set up colors and line types by group. You however need to transform the data first to take full advantage of that:

```r
library(tidyr)

CA <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30)
Xb_exp <- c(0.0231,0.0519,0.0839,0.1197,0.1595,0.1996,0.2384,0.2772,0.3153,0.3520,0.3887,0.4254,0.4615,0.4978,0.5339,0.5685,0.6000,0.6279,0.6528,0.6762,0.6974,0.7166,0.7346,0.7516,0.7669,0.7810,0.7940,0.8059)
Xb_dw <- c(0.0160,0.0516,0.0886,0.1259,0.1633,0.2006,0.2377,0.2749,0.3122,0.3496,0.3870,0.4245,0.4617,0.4984,0.5339,0.5678,0.5996,0.6288,0.6551,0.6786,0.6994,0.7179,0.7346,0.7499,0.7641,0.7774,0.7899,0.8018)
Xb_f <- c(0.0021,0.0031,0.0046,0.0067,0.0095,0.0131,0.0177,0.0234,0.0387,0.0483,0.0591,0.0709,0.0832,0.0955,0.1073,0.1181,0.1272,0.1345,0.1398,0.1443,0.1456,0.1468,0.1474,0.1476,0.1477,0.1477,0.1477,0.1477)
Xb_s <- c(0.0139,0.0484,0.0839,0.1192,0.1538,0.1874,0.2200,0.2515,0.2818,0.3108,0.3387,0.3653,0.3908,0.4151,0.4383,0.4604,0.4815,0.5015,0.5206,0.5387,0.5559,0.5722,0.5877,0.6024,0.6164,0.6264,0.6421,0.6040)

dat <- data.frame(CA, Xb_exp, Xb_dw, Xb_f, Xb_s)

color4 <- c("Xb_exp"="#3C5488FF", "Xb_dw"="#DC0000FF", "Xb_f"="#00A087FF", "Xb_s"="#4DBBD5FF")

linetypes <- c( Xb_dw="solid", Xb_f="dotted", Xb_s="longdash" )

dat2 <- pivot_longer( dat, cols=starts_with("Xb_") )
dat2.line <- dat2 %>% filter( name != "Xb_exp" )
dat2.point <- dat2 %>% filter( name == "Xb_exp" )
```

`dat2` is now a *long* data set, with data category as a variable, not with a separate column for each data series. This is how ggplot likes it:

```r
dat2
```

```
# A tibble: 112 x 3
      CA name    value
   <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>
 1     3 Xb_exp 0.0231
 2     3 Xb_dw  0.016 
 3     3 Xb_f   0.0021
 4     3 Xb_s   0.0139
 5     4 Xb_exp 0.0519
 6     4 Xb_dw  0.0516
 7     4 Xb_f   0.0031
 8     4 Xb_s   0.0484
 9     5 Xb_exp 0.0839
10     5 Xb_dw  0.0886
# … with 102 more rows
```

I then split the data on what later goes to points and what goes ot lines, just not to make the plot code uglier than it has to be:

```r
Xb_D1 <- ggplot(data = dat2.line, aes(x=CA,y=value,color=name)) +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(x="Crank position (ºCA)", y= bquote('Burn fraction ('~X[b]~')')) +
    geom_point( data = dat2.point, size=3) +
    geom_line( aes(col=name,lty=name), size=1 ) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=color4) +
    scale_linetype_manual( values=linetypes, guide=FALSE ) +
    guides(
        color = guide_legend( override.aes=list( shape=c(NA,19,NA,NA), linetype=c("solid","solid","dashed","dotted") ) )
    ) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank(),legend.position = c(0.8, 0.5),
          legend.text.align = 0,
          legend.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2,30))
print(Xb_D1)
```

- no need to supply labels
- use line type as you would use color with ggplot, its just one more channel that can carry information (or *aesthetic* as they like to call it over there)
- align the legends left, looks nicer that way
- more sophisticated is the use of override.aes to take away the points from the legend categories who shouldn't have them.

Now, I was unable to change the order of the data series in the labels, that can be a hazzle. Is it still ok for you the order they are?

[image: the plot]

Comment: note, if you change the order of the legend labels, you have to also change the override.aes, it did not accept a named list/vector (which was a disapointment)

Comment: Thanks Sirius for the time to reply, but I have not solved my problem. The expression with a subscript does not appear on the label (as in the attached figure). The type of line does not appear on the label. And the order of the label is not correct. Is there any way to solve this.

Comment: I was able to change lty for the 3 non blue series, but was not allowed to set NA for the blue one, so it remains with a dot and a line. furthermore the legends aren't really that good at this scale. I suspect the order can be changed with some trickery, (setting factor levels in the right order did not work). But at this point I suspect you are at the end of the compelxity ggplot can offer. It is an under-communicated truth that ggplot is good at quickly whipping up a figure, but the moment you need to fiddle with it to get it right in all aspects the conventional ploting framework is as fast

Comment: Thanks Sirius. Perhaps the option will be to use the conventional framework.
And there is a way to use the subscript in the label expression.

Comment: Yeah, see my other answer below